# R sommer package: predict.mmer does not work with Dtable from mmer model

Tags: r, mixed-models

I have a multi-environment-trial dataset, for which i want to calculate system specific genotype BLUPs for the tested varieties. There are several locations nested in system (on-station and on-farm). Some genotypes were only tested on-station and are to be blocked out, hence the variable "KEEP" has a level for each genotype of interest and a common level for the genotypes to be blocked out. This is my model:

```
mod <- mmer(PrefScoreAll ~ SYSTEM + SYSTEM:OS,
             random = ~ SYSTEM:LOCATION +
                        vsr(usr(SYSTEM), KEEP) + 
                        SYSTEM:KEEP:LOCATION + 
                        vsr(dsr(SYSTEM),LOCATION:REP) + 
                        vsr(dsr(SYSTEM),LOCATION:REP:IBLOCK),
             
             rcov = ~ vsr(dsr(LOCATION),units),
             naMethodY = "exclude",
             data = data)
```

Now, when i want to calculate predictions with predict.mmer, i get the following error:

```
predict.mmer(mod, D="KEEP")

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "start", value = c(1, 2, 3, 36, 52,  : 
  replacement has 12 rows, data has 11
```

The problem seems to be the Dtable itself, not the allocation of terms to "include" or "average". This is the Dtable i get from the model:

```
   type                 term include average
1   fixed                    1   FALSE   FALSE
2   fixed               SYSTEM   FALSE   FALSE
3   fixed            SYSTEM:OS   FALSE   FALSE
4  random      SYSTEM:LOCATION   FALSE   FALSE
5  random               SYSTEM   FALSE   FALSE
6  random                 KEEP   FALSE   FALSE
7  random SYSTEM:KEEP:LOCATION   FALSE   FALSE
8  random               SYSTEM   FALSE   FALSE
9  random         LOCATION:REP   FALSE   FALSE
10 random               SYSTEM   FALSE   FALSE
11 random  LOCATION:REP:IBLOCK   FALSE   FALSE
```

When i add an empty row underneath (with FALSE for both include and average) it calculates something, but as start and end values are allocated to the empty column then, i doubt the results are right.

Can somebody help me fix this and show how to get BLUPs specific for the system?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? That way I could see what's the problem.